# Can I redirect to another url in a django TemplateView?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a url mapping that looks like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<lang>[a-z][a-z])/$', MyTemplateView.as_view()),
```

There are only a few values that I accept for the `lang` capture group, that is: (1) `ro` and (2) `en`. If the user types `http://server/app/fr/`, I want to redirect it to the default `http://server/app/en/`.

How can I do this since `MyTemplateView` only has a method that is expected to return a dictionary?

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    return { 'foo': 'blah' }
```

Answer (score 50):

I know this question is old, but I've just done this myself. A reason you may think you want to do it in `get_context_data` is due to business logic, but you should place it in `dispatch`.

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')

    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Keep your business logic in your `dispatch` and you should be golden.

Answer (score 15):

Why only `get_context_data`?

Just set up your `get` handler to do a redirect if necessary.

```
def get(self, request, lang):
    if lang == 'fr':
         return http.HttpResponseRedirect('../en')

     return super(MyTemplateView, self).get(request, lang)
```

Answer (score 2):

A note from the future: it's now possible and probably simpler just to use [`RedirectView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me using an [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) class in Django 3.1:

```py
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
   
    if 1 == 1:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy("view_name_here"))
    else:
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

To determine this, I analyzed its base class (Cmd+Click in PyCharm), where I found the base method:

```py
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

You can find this and other methods in the Django source code: [`django/views/generic/edit.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2b443cb6c2d55669b20019f2755c0711c3d23050/django/views/generic/edit.py#L188)