# how to redirect url in django's templateview

Tags: django, redirect

i have a templateview,the code is here so how do

```
class MyTemplateView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UBaseTemplateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # i want to redirect another url in here
        # how to do it

        return context
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I redirect to another url in a django TemplateView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884766/can-i-redirect-to-another-url-in-a-django-templateview)

Answer (score 8):

Well, you would so something like this:

```
class MyTemplateView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/<your path here>/')
```

You can learn more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-simple-form), and in more detail [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/).

If you want to pass on post data, then all you have to do is this:

```
class MyTemplateView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('/<your url here>/', [params]))
```

You can also do this using the `post` function.

```
class MyTemplateView(TemplateView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # do what you want with post data
        # you can get access via request.POST.get()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/<your url>/')
        # Or use the above example's return statement, if you want to pass along parameters
```

Comment: i know this way.but i deal with post data in get_context_data(self, **kwargs), so i want to redirect another url after done the post data

Comment: I wouldn't recommend redirecting within the `get_context_data` step, keep that logic in your post or get method where it belongs. It's perfectly possible to determine what to do by the return of your `get_context_data` method

Comment: @Hedde: I agree, its better to use `get` or `post` to do that kind of stuff for you, you gain a lot more flexibility too.

Comment: with post method is an idea i wanted to do post and get in one method

Comment: Not working for me in Django 3.2 and get_context_data(): `context must be a dict rather than HttpResponseRedirect.`

Answer (score 0):

A more generic way to do this is with dispatch() as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884766/can-i-redirect-to-another-url-in-a-django-templateview). More background on what dispatch does is [in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/intro/).

The advantage is that this is going to work whatever HTTP method (GET, PUT, POST etc) has been specified on the request, whereas the get() function's only going to get called if the method is GET.